# I need a way to map two separate actions to mouse 1 in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a reaction time test (with a twist) in pygame.
I understand that the code in my event loop for mouse_clicks[0] (ie: left mouse button) can register whether or not you've clicked in the area for a small circle. However, I wish to have another action for left mouse button once I figure out how to code the event loop for when a big circle flashes on the screen. So, pretty much the same action for mouse_clicks[0] but with "if math.sqrt(sqx + sqy) < CIRCLE_RADIUS_LARGE". How could I achieve this using the pygame event loop. This is my first independent pygame so any help would be greatly appreciated. Much love, cLappy.

```
while running:
    Clock.tick(FPS)

    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    mouse_clicks = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()

    for event in event_list:
        if mouse_clicks[2]:
            pygame.display.update()
            SCREEN.fill(BLACK)
            circle(BLUE, CIRCLE_RADIUS_SMALL)
        if mouse_clicks[0]:
            x = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0]
            y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1]

            sqx = (x - 640) ** 2
            sqy = (y - 360) ** 2

            if math.sqrt(sqx + sqy) < CIRCLE_RADIUS_SMALL:
                reset_circle(BLUE, CIRCLE_RADIUS_SMALL)
                pygame.display.update()
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

Comment: BiRD, this does not answer the question at hand. How would I map two separate actions to the same click in the pygame event loop? I already distinguished between left and right clicks in the code I have already.

Comment: Hi. I'm not getting very clearely what you are trying to do. In your example you don't use the events from the loop except for the quit event, so in the current state, all the conditions blocks for mouse_clicks[0] and mouse_clicks[2] could (should?) be outside of the event loop. Anyway, could you give more description about what you want to do and why you don't get to achieve it ?

Comment: `pygame.display.update()` must be called at the very end of your main loop as it updates the display.  here the `SCREEN.fill(BLACK)` instruction won't have any visible effect as long as `pygame.display.update()` is not called (i.e., at the next iteration, if an event is catched and if the button is still pressed).

Answer (score 0):

You must draw the objects in the application loop, but not in the event loop. The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- limit the frames per second to limit CPU usage with [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock)
- handle the events by calling either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by calling either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

Minimal example

[image]

```py
import pygame, math

pygame.init()
SCREEN = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))

CIRCLE_RADIUS_SMALL = 20
circles = []

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(100)

    event_list = pygame.event.get()
    for event in event_list:
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1:
                circles.append(event.pos)
            if event.button == 3:
                for center in circles[:]:
                    dx = center[0] - event.pos[0]
                    dy = center[1] - event.pos[1]
                    if math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) < CIRCLE_RADIUS_SMALL:
                        circles.remove(center)
 
    SCREEN.fill("black")
    for center in circles:
        pygame.draw.circle(SCREEN, "blue", center, CIRCLE_RADIUS_SMALL)
    pygame.display.update()
```